# Django ORM order by filters

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-orm, django-database

Help me please with my problem. I want to get objects sorted first by one filter and then by another filter.

***How can I get objects with this ordering in 1 query to the DB (need for pagination)?***

This example shows queryset without ordering:

```
rooms = Room.objects.filter(Q(name__icontains=search) | Q(owner__username__icontains=search))
```

I have the room model:

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Room(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**views.py** (my bad code)

```
class RoomListView(ListAPIView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        search = 'test' #  for example
        rooms1 = Room.objects.filter(owner__username__icontains=search)
        rooms2 = Room.objects.filter(name__icontains=search)
        return list(rooms1) + list(rooms2)
```

**The wrong result:** search = "test"

```
[
  {
    "id":1,
    "name":"test",
    "owner":{
      "username":"user1"
    }
  },
  {
    "id":2,
    "name":"room1",
    "owner":{
      "username":"test"
    }
  },
  {
    "id":3,
    "name":"test2",
    "owner":{
      "username":"user2"
    }
  }
]
```

**The correct result:** search = "test"

```
[
  {
    "id":2,
    "name":"room1",
    "owner":{
      "username":"test"
    }
  },
  {
    "id":1,
    "name":"test",
    "owner":{
      "username":"user1"
    }
  },
  {
    "id":3,
    "name":"test2",
    "owner":{
      "username":"user2"
    }
  }
]
```

***How can I get objects with this ordering in 1 query to the DB (need for pagination)?***

Answer (score 2):

As I understand you want to filter and order the rows with multi columns

#### For `single` column sorting

```
rooms = Room.objects.filter(Q(name__icontains=search) | Q(owner__username__icontains=search)).order_by('name')
```

#### For `multi` columns sorting

Here, we can order the columns with `owner_username` and same *owner_username* rows will be order_by with `name`

```
rooms = Room.objects.filter(Q(name__icontains=search) | Q(owner__username__icontains=search)).order_by('owner__username', 'name')
```

#### Note

- You can sort the columns by using `order_by()`
- Example

  ```
  # Sorting order will in the order of column_1, column_2, column_3
  Room.objects.filter(.....).order_by('column_1', 'column_2', 'column_3)
  ```
- You can change the order of columns according to the requirements

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this is a little different. I need a list that will start with objects from one filter and then from the second. In your example, everything is mixed :(

Answer (score 0):

- You can sort the columns by using `order_by()`
- Example

  ```
  # Sorting columns with id, name, username in dynamically 
  order_by_list = []
  # sort by name
  order_by_list.append('name')
  # And second username sort along with name
  order_by_list.append('owner__username')
  ```

  ```
  Room.objects.filter(.....).order_by(*order_by_list)
  ```
- Here, we can `append` the `column` names dynamically to `order_by_list`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this is a little different. 
I wont to get objects with "owner__username" == search and then get objects with "name" == search. Look at "views.py (my bad code)" in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Use CASE WHEN expression and mark correct filter condition by integer. Pseudocode:
case when username = test then 1 when room = test then 2 ... END "CASECOL"
order by "CASECOL" ASC